# Django | 2 foreignkey to oneself model shows error | Just one foreignkey to oneself works fine

Tags: django, django-models

In a model.py named Station, i have 2 index with fireignkey to the same models.py (station). If i use only one index with this relation, this works ok. But if i have a second index relation to the same models.py(Station) it works bad with error message:

**Error:**

```
station.Station.comunication_point: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'Station.comunication_point' clashes with reverse accessor for 'Station.origin_watertank'.
        HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'Station.comunication_point' or 'Station.origin_watertank'.
station.Station.origin_watertank: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'Station.origin_watertank' clashes with reverse accessor for 'Station.comunication_point'.
        HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'Station.origin_watertank' or 'Station.comunication_point'.

System check identified 2 issues (0 silenced).
```

**How can i do 2 foreignkey to oneself model without error? Thanks!**

2 index with foreignkey to Station models.py

```
origin_watertank = models.ForeignKey ('self', null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True)
comunication_point =  models.ForeignKey ('self', null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True)
```

**File** models.py:

```
class Station(models.Model):
    timestamp_station = models.DateTimeField ('Fecha edición',null=True, blank=True)
    code_station = models.CharField('Código',max_length=50,null=True, blank=True)
    name_station = models.CharField('Nombre',max_length=50,null=True, blank=True) 
    origin_watertank = models.ForeignKey ('self', null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True)    
    comunication_point =  models.ForeignKey ('self', null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True)
    
    objects = StationManager()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Station'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Stations'

    def __str__(self):
        #return  [self.name,self.area,self.codigo]
        return str(self.id) + '-' + str(self.name_station)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `related_name` as mentioned in the error:

```
origin_watertank = models.ForeignKey ('self', null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, related_name="origins")
comunication_point =  models.ForeignKey ('self', null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, related_name="comunications")
```

You have two foreign keys to the same source so to be able to do reverse lookups, you need to provide a `related_name` for each so Django can separate them.

This will allow you to make this kind of lookups:

```
station = Station.objects.get(pk=1)

# will return all the stations based on comunication_point
stations.comunications.all()

# will return all the stations based on origin_watertank
stations.origins.all()
```

feel free to change the names.